# Problem in enabling APC on PHP 5.3.6

Tags: php

I am having a problem in enabling the APC Cache. Here is my configuration.

```
PHP 5.3.6
Apache 2.2.19
Windows 7
```

I have downloaded the php_apc.dll from below URl:
http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_apc-20110109-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip

I have placed that dll in php's extension folder and placed the below code in php.ini

```
extension=php_apc.dll
```

Next anything remain to be enable the APC cache? Because when I place above line in PHP.ini then apache is not restarting.

Any help much appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
[Tue Sep 06 14:22:28 2011] [notice] Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
[Tue Sep 06 14:22:33 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
rocess is ending.
[Tue Sep 06 14:22:29 2011] [notice] Child 4212: Released the start mutex
[Tue Sep 06 14:23:00 2011] [notice] Child 4212: Waiting 270 more seconds for 1 worker threads to finish.
[Tue Sep 06 14:23:04 2011] [notice] Child 4212: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Sep 06 14:23:04 2011] [notice] Child 4212: Child process is exiting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens in Apache's main `error.log` when you restart it? This should give you a clue what is wrong...

Also since you are running PHP under Apache, I'm guessing you are probably running the Thread-Safe version (Non Thread-Safe versions are mainly for running PHP as an ISAPI module under IIS), and the file you have downloaded seems to be Non Thread-Safe (it has `nts` in the file name). You should be using the Thread-Safe build with Apache - try using [this file](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_apc-20110109-5.3-vc9-x86.zip) instead.

Also, make sure you are using a VC9 build of PHP distributed from php.net - the DLL will have been built against these releases and is not guaranteed to work with anyone else's distributions. It is certainly not guaranteed to work with a VC6 build, if for some reason this is what you are using.

Where is your Apache build from?

Comment: I have placed the error from error.log in question edit section...

Comment: There is no obvious reason for your problem in that error log, are you using seperate PHP/Apache installs or a package like WAMP/XAMPP?

Comment: separate PHP/Apache install,
Apache 2.2.20 (win32), mod_ssl/2.2.20 Open SSL/0.9.8r PHP/5.3.5

Comment: Is your PHP build a thread-safe VC9 build obtained directly from php.net? And where did you get your Apache build from? php.net 5.3 VC9 builds are built against Apache VC9 builds from http://www.apachelounge.com/

Comment: I have downloaded both from their offcial sites only. And yes PHP is VC9 Thread Safe as its the only option for windows..

Comment: You need to use the Apache build from http://www.apachelounge.com - this note from http://windows.php.net/download/ - `Do NOT use VC9 version with apache.org binaries. VC9 versions of Apache can be fetched at Apache Lounge. We use their binaries to build the Apache SAPIs.`

Comment: for PHP I have downloaded this one.. "php-5.3-ts-VC9-x86" is this one ok?

Comment: Yes that should be the one you want, this also means you should use the APC binary I linked to in my answer (the thread-safe one)

Comment: and for apache I have not downloaded from the link you have given, Is that ok?

Comment: No, as it states on the PHP.net download page, you **MUST** use VC9 PHP builds with VC9 Apache builds, and Apache do not build their own VC9 releases. The VC9 Apache builds that PHP 5.3 is built against can be obtained from Apache lounge. Read the notes on the left hand side of the [Windows Binaries download page at php.net](http://windows.php.net/download/)...

Comment: i have downloaded the apache from the link you have given. And found folder but not the .exe file? How to use that?

Comment: You should find that the contents of the folder is the same as the contents of your existing Apache installation. Backup your Apache configuration files, then uninstall Apache and unzip the folder to where Apache used to be installed. You *should* be able to just put your original config files back into the `conf` directory, and start Apache. You may need to install as a service, in which case you can run `httpd -k install`. To be honest, you need to know quite a bit about how to manually configure Apache if anything goes wrong... It might even be worth starting a fresh question here

Comment: great help man... Thanks a lot.. I have installed/configured PHP and APACHE as you have said and all works very well... APC is enabled now..

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working ;-) - It is very annoying that php.net have decided to stop offering VC6 builds of PHP as it has broken most of the old PECL dlls, and it has made it a lot more confusing to set up a new install - as you have discovered...

Comment: yes, I have got something new for my knowledge base...